# Writing a TypeScript decorator to always bind class methods to 'this'

Tags: class, typescript, scope, decorator, abstract

I'm attempting to write a decorator to always bind the scope of a class method to the instance of that class.

This is my implementation so far:

```
function LockThis<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
  let self: any;
  const locker = class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      self = this;
    }
  };
  const proto = constructor.prototype;
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto).forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'constructor') {
      return;
    }
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, key);
    if (descriptor && typeof descriptor.value === 'function') {
      const original = descriptor.value;
      locker.prototype[key] = (...a: any[]) => original.apply(self, a);
    }
  });
  return locker;
}

@LockThis
class Something {
  private foo = 'bar';

  public doIt(someVar?: string) {
    return this.foo + ' ' + someVar;
  }
}

const something = new Something();
console.log(something.doIt.call({}, 'test'));
--> bar test
```

This works, except on abstract classes:

```
@LockThis
abstract class Blah {

}

TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Blah' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => {}'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

Is there a different type guard to use to allow both actual classes and abstract classes and/or a way to do this per-method instead?

(My attempts at per-method have been futile since I can't seem to determine 'this' until the method is being invoked, which is too late if called with a different scope)

```
class Something {
  private foo = 'bar';

  @LockThis()
  public doIt(someVar?: string) {
    return this.stuff + ' ' + someVar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft/TypeScript#5843](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5843), there's no great way to refer to an abstract constructor type.  The workaround mentioned in there is to use just `Function`, which is too permissive (not all functions are constructors), but might work for you, since you are not likely to try to use a class decorator on a random function.

And you can't do a mixin on a `Function`, so the implementation needs to still think you've got a constructor.  Therefore I'd suggest you use a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) on `LockThis`, so that callers see `Function` but the implementation still sees a constructor it can extend.  For example:

```
// callers see a function that takes any function and returns the same type
function LockThis<T extends Function>(constructor: T): T;

// implementation is unchanged, and still sees a (concrete) constructor
function LockThis<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
  // ... your unchanged implementation here
}
```

And this works now:

```
@LockThis // no error
abstract class Blah { }
```

It's the closest I can get to what you want.  Hope that helps; good luck!